# Correcting the connection string inside a published ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

I don't have the source code of an application, but the published version. (So I only have .aspx files) I realized that the connection string for this application was inside a .vb file before it is published. However we have made changes with the database, so the old database does not exist anymore. How can I correct the connection string?

Comment: Connection string is usually stored in the web.config for security reasons so its not accessible to public because it contains username and password to the db ( email etc ). You can provide your connection string by creating another web.config file and recompiling your project ( dont forget to set references to the new webconfig ), or you can specify the connection string in each of the aspx files ( but thats called bad design )

Comment: @mehow Actually that is the problem, I am not able to recompile. The connection string is inside a button's click event, not in the web.config. So canceling the connection string is not possible. It is totally embedded inside the source code.

Comment: if you cannot access that .vb file, or that event - then its impossible for you to retrieve the string. Unless there is a public property to retrieve the string which i doubt there is

Answer (score 0):

You have to change that class for that particular page in the page directive and for that you have to rewrite the whole functionality of that class. and build and publish again